# Android MessagePassing through bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am developing an app for pass messages through bluetooth.I want to pass one message from one device to other device (Device is already paired) I am able to display the paired devices.But I dont know how to connect two devices.Can anyone tell me what are the steps should i follow.How to create connection between two phones ?

```
      public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  TextView textview1;
  private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
  BluetoothAdapter btAdapter; 

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // Getting the Bluetooth adapter
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    textview1.append("\nAdapter: " + btAdapter);

    CheckBluetoothState();
  }

  /* It is called when an activity completes.*/
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
      CheckBluetoothState();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  private void CheckBluetoothState() {
    // Checks for the Bluetooth support and then makes sure it is turned on
    // If it isn't turned on, request to turn it on
    // List paired devices
    if(btAdapter==null) { 
      textview1.append("\nBluetooth NOT supported. Aborting.");
      return;
    } else {
      if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        textview1.append("\nBluetooth is enabled...");

        // Listing paired devices
        textview1.append("\nPaired Devices are:");
        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
          textview1.append("\n  Device: " + device.getName() + ", " + device);
        }
      } else {
        //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
      }
    }
  }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `textView`, use ListView and add `items` to it the same way you have added them to `textView`.

```
//declaration in class
ListView  lview;
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

//in onCreate()

lview  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPairedDev);
lview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

///////here it gets added to list
ArrayOfDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                    if(ArrayOfDevices.size()>0)//paired dev more than 0
                    {
                        for(BluetoothDevice device: ArrayOfDevices)
                        {
                            listAdapter.add(device.getName()+ "\n" +device.getAddress());

                        }
                    }
```

and read about how to add anonymous `onClickListener` or types of action listenrs.
this has method which looks like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


//Click event on individual item of list.



}
```

when you set click event, set a server which will listen to your message sending scream. that will be a server(set as a server, don't take my words as they are).
before that make sure your app is connected to server, using a thread. you can read more about android threads. connection to server (other app acting as server), android permissions in manifest file, like bluetooth and admins are important. And god forbid if its a two way communication app, passing two way messages, then you have to do the same coding to handle server as well as client in both apps.